# Determine Partition OS

Tags: linux, bash, partitioning, bash-scripting

Is anyone aware of a way to determine the OS installed on a separate unmounted partition without mounting  it in Linux? I'm trying to determine which has Windows installed with a script while live booted into Linux and can't seem to figure out how.

It'd run in a rc.local so I can't easily prompt the user (I could exit Plymouth, but I would rather not)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To examine the filesystem itself, rather than just a partition type code, you can use the `blkid` utility in Linux. You can pass it a partition identifier or use it without any options to have it examine all the disk devices:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="66F7-FD24" TYPE="vfat"
```

Of course, the filesystem type isn't entirely diagnostic; FAT can be used by just about any OS, for instance. (In the case of this example, the partition is actually an [EFI System Partition (ESP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which holds boot loader files.) An NTFS partition might be a Windows boot partition, a Windows emergency recovery partition, or a non-bootable data partition. Depending on how robust your script must be, you may need to mount the partition and start looking for diagnostic files to figure out a partition's purpose.

Comment: `blkid` is a good suggestion.  Also, you have a good list of relevant caveats. +1

Answer (score 1):

This will get a list of NTFS partitions:

```
fdisk -l | awk '/NTFS/{print $1;}'
```

You didn't say what you wanted to do with this information. Note that not all of these partitions are necessarily bootable.

Rod Smith suggests the use of `blkid`.  To get a similar list of NTFS partitions from `blkid`, use:

```
blkid -t TYPE="ntfs" -o device
```

Comment: Fair enough. It's to mess with system32 basically. Thanks.

Comment: That just examines the partition type code, which might not be accurate. Also, until recently `fdisk` didn't work with GPT disks, so this test will fail on GPT disks with older versions of `fdisk`, such as the one that's still used with Ubuntu 14.04 (the latest long-term support version of Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the storage device's partition table to find the partition type. If it's NTFS, it's probably some flavor of Windows. If it's ext4, it's probably some flavor of Linux. If it's some flavor HFS+, it's probably some flavor of OS X.